# On redash how to create a chart that shows counts of types

Tags: mongodb, data-visualization

I am trying to create something similar to the example here:

http://demo.redash.io/embed/query/387/visualization/518?api_key=cc11cd75d4f3934b17de1f0621abd2f0c9cce713

But I can not figure it out. If someone can explain how to create this specific chart it would be great.

You can assume I am using a similar dataset and query with mongodb.

This is the demo link with the query:
http://demo.redash.io/queries/387/source#518

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps are:

1. You write the query, run it and get the results.
2. Click on "+ New Visualization" (next to the table header).
3. Define your chart/visualization.

But it's really hard to understand what part you can't figure out - do you have problem getting the results? Defining the chart?

In the future, it's better to use the [Redash's forum](https://discuss.redash.io) for such questions, as I stumbled at this question by chance.

Comment: I got the query results fine. The problem is building the chart. I can not edit the chart, hence can not see what parameters have been chosen for building it. If you could share screenshots of the edit page of the chart in the example it would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Here you go: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s7/sh/9155e640-b686-43be-b1f8-ea867095cb6f/b9e16a4a975136a2/res/d6ee71d6-d34e-46bf-86c7-400481556890/skitch.png?resizeSmall&width=832